# Scatter plot of dates and times

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of `datetime.datetime` objects I want to represent in a scatter plot similar to this one:

[image]
<sub>(source: [stephenwolfram.com](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2012/03/outgoing-mail-diurnal-image.png))</sub>

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pylab

# datetimes = [datetime(...), ...]

pylab.plot([dt.date() for dt in datetimes],
           [dt.hour + dt.minute/60. for dt in datetimes],
           ',')
```

Comment: +1.  Google also turns up [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=scatter%20plot#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

Comment: Thank you!  I was using `dt.time()` instead of `dt.hour + dt.minute / 60.0`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Oddly, `marker=','` isn't working with `scatter()`.